# MPDF Ignoring inputs in Call

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm trying to use mpdf as I was used to on another server using this commands:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4','','' , 30, 30, 30, 30, 0 , 0);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
```

But mpdf ignores my margins. equal to if i set them to 300, 30 or 600, the result always looks the same.
Documentation: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184

Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Comment: It works, atleast here v5.6 - what mpdf version are you using? It should be above 5.0.

Comment: I'm using v5.6 aswell. And as I mentioned earlier, it already worked on another server - that's the main issue that gives me headache.